# Print to Sublimetext Status bar in Python?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

In SublimeText 2, which uses Python plugins.  I am trying to enhance an existing plugin that I found.

Basically it is a timer plugin that has `start`, `stop`, `pause` functionality and will print the Times to the Status bar using this Sublimetext API call...

`sublime.status_message(TIMER)`

What I would like to do is show something in the `Status Bar` to show that a Timer is in fact started and running.  Something like this...

`sublime.status_message('Timer: on')`

The problem is this just briefly shows my Status bar message for a few seconds before being dismissed.

So I am looking for information on how to print to the status bar and keep it there long term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `view.set_status(key, value)` to place a persisting message in the status bar. However, this is bound to a view, not the application. If you need the message independent of the view, you will have to do some work using activated and deactivated listeners. Alternatively, you can set the status on all views in the window by using `window.views()` to get an array of all the views in the window, and place the status message on all of the views. Then, when you are done, remove all of the status messages.

Comment: Yes I found that `view.set_status(key, value)` yesterday and tried a bunch of different methods to get it working on my existing class or method with no luck, I then assumed I need to get access to that View class somehow so your post makes that more clear now.  I have literally no experience with Python so I don't nderstand it all but from my other experience I have been able to get it somewhat working.  I think the Listeners is the solution here, I'll try that out, thanks

Answer (score 2):

please reference below code.
This is a class that clear the status after specified time period expired, and to use this class, just call set_status() function.

```
import time, threading

class StatusDisplay:
  def __init__(self):
    self.timeout = 3
    self.timer = None

  def set_status(self, view, msg, overwrite):
    self.cancel_timer()
    self.view = view
    if overwrite:
        self.view.set_status("mytag", msg+'\n')
    else:
        self.view.set_status("mytag", msg)
    self.start_timer()

  def cancel_timer(self):
    if self.timer != None:
        self.timer.cancel()

  def start_timer(self):
    self.timer = threading.Timer(self.timeout, self.clear)
    self.timer.start()

  def clear(self):
    print('clear message')
    self.view.erase_status("mytag")
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really run across any plugins that can keep a message in the status bar for very long. This is probably an intentional design decision, so users can access the status bar menus, and plugins don't hijack other messages that need to be shown, like the cursor position.

Check out [ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter) for options on printing messages to different places. In particular, via user setting it can print to the status bar, clipboard, a panel, and/or the console log.